# Event Driven architecture - right way to build chain of events

Tags: architecture, event-programming

Let's say we have a ecommerce platform.
When user create order - we should make several actions like

- Send push to client
- Send push to custome
- Send emails
- e.t.c

Generally I see two diffrent aproaches to arrange it.
Is there some more right way to do it?

**First:**

In `orderController` Push One message "`createOrder`" to MQ:
then dedicated handler will split this message to few messages like (`pushOrderMessageToClient`, `pushOrderMessageToCustomer` and etc) and push them to Message queue.

**Second:**

In `orderController` push few messages like (`pushOrderMessageToClient`, `pushOrderMessageToCustomer` and etc) without one general "createOrder" event

Comment: Or #3. OrderControll is agnostic to whatever comes after an order is created or processed. It just notifies the entry of a new order. Others will handle this and do their job, for example, by pushing notifications. Event Driven is all about eventual consistency. The fact that you are thinking about `chaining` events should rise a red flag on how you are approaching this sort of thing. It might help to think of this as a choreography of events rather than a sequence of events.

Comment: @Laiv but how Others will know about a fact that order was created?

Comment: Because you will broadcast the event through, say a queue or stream. Other participants of the architecture will listen to these events but only react to very specific ones. This can happen within the boundary of a single application (something I don't recomend) or it can span multiple systems. It depends on what kind of architecture you have.

Comment: Laiv has the right approach.  Think of it as having commands and events.  A command is something like CreateOrder and an event is something like OrderCreated.  Commands are only handled by one subscriber and once the order is created it raises the OrderCreated event which may have many subscribers.  What is done by the subscribers of the OrderCreated event is no concern with the process that creates the order.